# Frequency and Volume Relational in Sound

Tags: acoustics, frequency, volume

In a real life example: Suppose if I change the volume of TV, Computer or, Stereo sound device, would the frequency of sound change as well? In other words, when I lower the volume does it make frequency go lower, higher or, stay constant?

Answer (score 1):

The only way loudness and pitch are related is in the details of how your ear operates. For *extremely loud* sounds, your ear tends to perceive the pitch of those sounds slightly flatter than when they are heard at normal loudness levels.

Another thing to note here is that when sounds are not very loud, the ear loses effectiveness at low frequencies, which then sound "weak in the mix". Many stereo playback systems contain a *contour network* which automatically boosts the loudness of the bass frequencies whenever the system is running at low loudness levels to make up for this tendency. This too is an effect that is *in your ear*, not in the physics of sound transmission through air.

Comment: So, to my original question. Should I take this as 'no, the frequency doesn't change with volume'?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is not link between the two.

We define the *frequency* (for a periodic wave) as the number of occurences of the wave per units of time. The *volume*, however, is a description of the amplitude of the wave.

That is, of course, for sonic waves.

Comment: It appears this implies when I change volume, amplitude changes while frequency stays same.